# Shifting an audio signal from 0 - 4V to -2 - 2V

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio, signal-processing

I'd like to transmit an audio signal over a digital radio and I figured out I'd need an op-amp in an inverting configuration on the transmitting side to turn a -2V to 2V signal into a 0-4V one. That will be fed into an ADC which then supplies the radio with a digital signal. On the receiving side though I'd need to do the reverse in order to hear the audio properly, so that means the 0-4V signal now needs to be the -2V to 2V one again. Could an op-amp also be used for this, and how? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could an op-amp also be used for this, and how?

No need to use an op-amp if your signal is audio. Shifting a biased audio signal of 0 - 4 volts to an unbiased voltage requires only a RC high pass filter. It will remove the DC offset: -

[image]

You decide on the values of R and C so that the lowest frequency you wish to pass is: -

$$F_{LOW} = \dfrac{1}{2\pi RC}$$